# XAMPP Web Page Not loading fully on other computer on network

Tags: php, html, apache, networking, xampp

http://192.168.14.23/training_guide
brings me to webpage. displays some css but no data from any of the html files within the directory

I went into my httpd.config file and changed some settings like

```
<Directory /> AllowOverride All Require all granted </Directory>
```

I have **XAMPP** running Apache web server and I built an html web page. On my computer everything loads great. The file paths work, the images load, css works. When I go to a different computer and go to http://localhost:80 My file directory appears. So I go to the directory with my page which is http://192.168.xx.xxx/training_guide and hardly anything loads. There are tons of errors in the console that say "404". "Err_not_found" or "unable to load local resource".

Like I said, I have all file paths and image paths correct. I have bootstrap downloaded locally and everything should work as normal. The links to each separate html page work too. I believe all of my configuration files are working too.

```
<div class="navDisplay"><a href="../Pages/references.html">References</a></div>
```

That is an example of path for one of my linked pages.

These are the paths for my bootstrap and css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\training_guide\Public\css\bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\Public\styles.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="..\Public\fonts.css">
```

A path to an image

```
<img id="roundImage" src="../Public/Images/cameras/h4esdomecamera.jpg" alt="H4 Dome" title="Click for more information">
```

and a path to a pdf file

```
<a href="../Public/References/cameras/H4ES/H4ESref.pdf" target="_blank">
```

It has to have something to do with the file paths, I just know it. How do I fix this?

My folder structure is as follows:

htdocs
training_guide
Pages
Public

Comment: When it works, do you see `file:///` in the address bar or `http://`

Comment: Make sure you're not using localhost in absolute paths like `<img src="http://localhost/icon.png">`.

Comment: _Small Point_ any IP starting `192.168.` is a private ip address and therefore we (outside your router) could not try and connect to it even if we wanted to. So you dont need to obfiscate it in any way

Comment: On my computer or the other one on the network?

Comment: Well both really

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you

Comment: @AlexHowansky I do not have any paths like that. I am going to add some info

Comment: I mean in the address bar of your browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here is my url "http://localhost:81/training_guide/index.html"

Comment: I added code and path examples. Let me know what else I can add.

Comment: If this `http://192.168.xx.xxx/training_guide` works then you must have a `.htaccess` file. Did you move that too

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not see that file. It is not in my htdocs folder

Comment: htdocs -> training_guide -> Pages , Public, Index.html

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried to message you but I am not allowed